# Dynamic Image Imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a component where I need to use specific images where there are more than 28 options, so I wrote 2 functions, they look like so, to dynamically import images:

```js
    loadAvatar = imageName => {
        // Imports Avatar image file and returns it
        import(`../../../img/avatars/${imageName}.svg`).then(image => {
            return image;
        });
    };

    getAvatarIcon(icon, color) {
        // Uses Avatar icon and color defined in endpoint response to return proper file name
        var avatarFileName = "Avatar_" + icon + "_" + color;
        return this.loadAvatar(avatarFileName);
    }
```

and I try to call it using this

```js
<img src={() => this.getAvatarIcon(icon, color)} alt={name} className="avatar" />
```

However, this is not working, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so I did a few things:

- Switched to require() instead of import() to get the image directly and not an object containing it as a param.
- Ran the function in ComponentDidMount() instead of the render() method to prevent an infinite loop.
- Saved the image in state and used it in my render() instead of returning a function value.

Here's how my end code looked like

```js
    // When Mount
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAvatarIcon(this.props.icon, this.props.color);
    }

    async getAvatarIcon(icon, color) {
        // Uses Avatar icon and color defined in endpoint response to return proper file name
        var avatarFileName = "Avatar_" + icon + "_" + color;
        return await this.loadAvatar(avatarFileName);
    }

    async loadAvatar(imageName) {
        // Imports Avatar image file and sets it in the component state
        const avatar = await require(`../../../img/avatars/${imageName}.svg`);
        this.setState({ avatar });
    }
```

and in my render
`<img src={avatar} alt={name} className="avatar" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<img src={this.getAvatarIcon(icon, color)} alt={name} className="avatar" />
```

edit your `loadAvatar` function to:

```js
loadAvatar = imageName => import(`../../../img/avatars/${imageName}.svg`);
```

and edit `getAvatarIcon` to:

```js
async getAvatarIcon(icon, color) {
    // Uses Avatar icon and color defined in endpoint response to return proper file name
    var avatarFileName = "Avatar_" + icon + "_" + color;
    return await this.loadAvatar(avatarFileName);
}
```

Comment: Now im just running and getting the alt text

Comment: Perhaps I need to async await it somehow?

Comment: I just tried this implementation, same behavior of alt text, if I log what has been imported in loadAvatar, I can see Pending promises being logged, maybe thats what needs to be async?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see the problem. I think you should go another way and create a separate component for displaying images and pass a specific image name into it. I`ve created some example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/j4xpw5gr/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, i've managed to do it without using a separate component, please take a look at my answer now

Comment: okay, looks good. I just did not know, that you are going to display only one image in the component.